# Sum attributes of each related record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, sum, relationship

In my Rails 3 I have the following models:

```
Animal
Claim
Exclusion
```

The model relations are as follows:

```
Animal has_one exclusion
Animal has_many claims
Claim has_one Animal
Exclusion belongs_to Animal
```

In the exclusions table I have the following columns:

```
animal_id, con1, con2, con3, con4, con5
```

In the claim table I have the following columns:

```
animal_id, con1, con2, con3, con4, con5, description, date
```

An exclusion has_one animal and a claim has_one animal. Animal has_many claims and has_one exclusion.

So, the user creates a claim which adds a value alongside each of the con* columns. How can I (in the Animal view) sum the total claimed for each condition?

For example; in my Animal view:

```
Condition 1 = 10.00
Condition 2 = 20.00
Condition 3 = 0.00
Condition 4 = 200.00
Condition 5 = 232.22
```

The values alongside the above conditions are taken from the following claims:

```
ID, con1, con2, con3, con4, con5, animal_id
-------------------------------------------
1,  5.00, 10.00, 0.00, 100.00, 200.00, 123
2,  5.00, 10.00, 0.00, 100.00, 32.22, 123
```

So the values of each condition is summed up across all claims belonging to the current animal.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nitpicking, but: `An exclusion has_one animal and a claim has_one animal.` this should be `An exclusion belongs_to one animal and a claim belongs_to one animal.`, right? Also in your list of model relations, claim should be: `Claim belongs_to Animal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your current animal is called `@animal`, then you can sum the values for a particular condition across all claims using the [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
con1_sum = @animal.claims.sum(:con1)
```

In your view, you could do something like this:

```
Condition 1 = <%= @animal.claims.sum(:con1) %>
Condition 2 = <%= @animal.claims.sum(:con2) %>
Condition 3 = <%= @animal.claims.sum(:con3) %>
Condition 4 = <%= @animal.claims.sum(:con4) %>
Condition 5 = <%= @animal.claims.sum(:con5) %>
```

It would probably make more sense to calculate these in the controller action rather than directly in the view, but anyway you get the idea.

Comment: +1 because it's easy to forget about ActiveRecord::Calculations (myself included :)